# ProgrammingError: (1064....)

Tags: python, mysql, yahoo-finance

I think this my seem elementary to a lot of people and it likely is, however, i am stuck.

I am taking some data from Yahoo and attempting to insert it into Mysql through python which i have done on many occassions...apart from this morning.

Here is the code...

```
result = ystockquote.get_price_book_ratio('aap')
cursor.execute("""UPDATE uk SET pricebook = %s, WHERE ID = %s""", (result,6))
```

I get this error for some reason

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ID = 6' at line 1")
```

I also tried...

```
    cursor.execute("""UPDATE uk SET pricebook = %s, WHERE symbol = %s""", (result,'aap'))
```

That too gave the same error message.

Comment: Why do you have "," after `%s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is invalid, you have a redundant "," after `%s`:

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE uk SET pricebook = %s, WHERE ID = %s""", (result,6))
                                              ↑
```

Remove it.